# rowspan not working html

Tags: html, css

I have a table and I am trying to accomplish something like this,[image]

So far I have following html, I think I can use rowspan but tried and it's not giving me desired outcome

```
<table class="table tab-content" style="width:95%" align="center">
    <tr class="row">
        <td colspan="2">
            <h4 class="h4">This is a new Car please call</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td style="width:100px; height=100%;" rowspan="2">
            <img width="100%" src="adimg/autos/11.jpg" />
        </td>
        <td style="width:70%">this is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ... &nbsp&nbsp <a style="font-weight:bold; color:Red" href="#">3 mins ago</a>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">$5000</td>
        <td><b>Smart Cars</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The thing you are trying to achieve will require a simple wrapper div with two nested floated divs, you don't have to use `table` for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got to place the rowspan `<td>` as the first element in your first `<tr>`.

The span works downward, so what you have right now is the second row spanning into the third.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4y30vvx/2/).

Comment: when I placed <td on second row in first place it's working as I wanted. added to your solution

Comment: You mean keeping the img td in the second row?  That results in a bad layout (you can edit the fiddle yourself and see what happens).

Answer (score 0):

Place the  with image in the top row , and it should work fine.

```
<table class="table tab-content" style="width:95%" align="center">
<tr class="row">
        <td style="width:100px; height=100%;" rowspan="2">
        <img width="100%" src="adimg/autos/11.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <h4 class="h4">This is a new Car please call</h4>
    </td>

</tr>
<tr class="row">

    <td style="width:70%">this is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ... &nbsp&nbsp <a style="font-weight:bold; color:Red" href="#">3 mins ago</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">$5000</td>
    <td><b>Smart Cars</b>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image should be on the top row with rowspan=2 which will put it in 2 rows. Also, the td containing  should have colspan=3 to cover the rest of the row. Colspan=2 here will leave a gap in this row above the cell "Smart Cars".
The second row automatically fits in the first column with the image since the rowspan given earlier and the remaining 3 columns of the row follows.

```
<table class="table tab-content" style="width:95%" align="center">
<tr class="row">
        <td style="width:100px; height=100%;" rowspan="2">
        <img width="100%" src="adimg/autos/11.jpg" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <h4 class="h4">This is a new Car please call</h4>
    </td>

</tr>
<tr class="row">

    <td style="width:70%">this is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ad this is a car adthis is a car adthis is a car ... &nbsp&nbsp <a style="font-weight:bold; color:Red" href="#">3 mins ago</a>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">$5000</td>
    <td><b>Smart Cars</b>
    </td>
</tr>
```